Making unauthenticated calls using Airflow API
I would like to make authenticated calls using Airflow Python Client library 2.5.1. I tried setting this setting in the config file: auth_backends = airflow.api.auth.backend.default like mentioned in the docs however it's returning an 403 code when I don't include the username and password in the Config (and returning 200 if I do include them)
For some context, I would like to add an additional layer of authentication above Airflow. I have a wrapper class for the Airflow Python Client Library ApiClient class because I'm planning to add some additional functionality to the library. As a result, I would like the base Client library to be able to make authenticated calls without auth.
